# Not able to save uploaded file on server using GOLANG and POLYMER http: no such file

Tags: go, polymer, vaadin

I am using vaadin upload to upload files on web application with polymer. And I am using golang for back-end.

```
<vaadin-upload target="../upload" max-files="20" accept="application/pdf,image/*" 
method="POST"> </vaadin-upload>
```

I checked that encoding type used in vaadin upload is **multipart/form-data**.
My golang code is below.

```
func upload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method)
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        crutime := time.Now().Unix()
        h := md5.New()
        io.WriteString(h, strconv.FormatInt(crutime, 10))
        token := fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))

        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("upload.gtpl")
        t.Execute(w, token)
    } else {
        r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("uploadFile")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v", handler.Header)
        f, err := os.OpenFile("./test/"+handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer f.Close()
        io.Copy(f, file)
    }
}
```

It gives error on server side **http: no such file**. I checked this error is returned by FormFile when the provided file field name is either not present in the request or not a file field.

**How do I correct my form file name**. Although everything seems fine on front-end
[image]

Comment: 1. Find out **where** your code fails. 2. Make sure stuff like `"./test/"+handler.Filename` actually produces something suitable for writing (e.g. ./test must exist).

Comment: My code fails at this part file, handler, err := r.FormFile("uploadFile")

Comment: That is what I want to know how do I handle this. I don't know what to write here FormFile("WHAT!!"). Because of this the code is giving error

Comment: Well, that's a vaadin-only question. Dump the request and see. Or track what your browser does with the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: May you add the full line of error? just to check what line is failing. Also I don't see the **name** field in your html tag, remember the value of the attribute **name** has to be the same for `r.FormFile("value_name")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answering my own question for those who are facing same problem. Found out some code which can access file without knowing the key value.**

```
func UploadHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {  
      var (  
           status int  
           err  error  
      )  
      defer func() {  
           if nil != err {  
                http.Error(res, err.Error(), status)  
           }  
      }()  
      // parse request  
     // const _24K = (1 << 20) * 24  
      if err = req.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20); nil != err {  
           status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
           return  
      } 
        fmt.Println("No memory problem")
      for _, fheaders := range req.MultipartForm.File {  
           for _, hdr := range fheaders {  
                // open uploaded  
                var infile multipart.File  
                if infile, err = hdr.Open(); nil != err {  
                     status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                     return  
                }  
                // open destination  
                var outfile *os.File  
                if outfile, err = os.Create("./uploaded/" + hdr.Filename); nil != err {  
                     status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                     return  
                }  
                // 32K buffer copy  
                var written int64  
                if written, err = io.Copy(outfile, infile); nil != err {  
                     status = http.StatusInternalServerError  
                     return  
                }  
                res.Write([]byte("uploaded file:" + hdr.Filename + ";length:" + strconv.Itoa(int(written))))  
           }  
      }  
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your final implementation. While posting your final solution for future programmers is very good, the accepted answer should go to @ain.

Comment: `32 << 20` is 32Mb. not 32Kb

Answer (score 4):

Did a quick test and it appears that the `vaadin-upload` uses `file` as the form data parameter name for the file. So in the line

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("uploadFile")
```

replace `uploadFile` with `file` and it should work.

It is [documented on the vaadin homepage](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-upload/vaadin-upload-server.html) that

> In order to support simultaneous uploads, instead of reusing the same FormData and XMLHttpRequest, we create a new one for each file. It is therefore alright for the server to only consider receiving one file per request.

However, I didn't see the parameter name (`file`) documented, so to be safe you should write your code so that it wouldn't use the name, ie something like

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
m := r.MultipartForm
for _, v := range m.File {
    for _, f := range v {
        file, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
        // do something with the file data
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes you are right. After posting this question I found some code same as your code for uploading without knowing the key value.

Comment: What headeache, I had the problem that only one file will upload and the others remain in cero bytes, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Use exactly the same name for doing r.FormFile("selectedFile") that is there in your HTML tag. The key is mapped to input name used in your frontend HTML tag.

Below is my implementation:

```
<file
    type="file"
    name="selectedFile"
/>

const (
    S3_REGION = "Your region"
    S3_BUCKET = "Your Bucket Name"
)

func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Uploading File")
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("selectedFile") // 
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
    }

    defer file.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Uploaded File: %+v\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Printf("File Size: %+v\n", handler.Size)
    fmt.Printf("MIME Header: %+v\n", handler.Header)

    s, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(S3_REGION)})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var size int64 = handler.Size
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)

    _, err = s3.New(s).PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String(S3_BUCKET),
        Key:                  aws.String(handler.Filename),
        ACL:                  aws.String("private"),
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType:          aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
        ContentDisposition:   aws.String("attachment"),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String("AES256"),
    })       
}
```