# Trying to recreate a mock version of a webservice

Tags: go

I am trying to emulate some APIs in Go for testing - I don't have the source code for the original API, but I can call them.

The thing I'm struggling with is that some of them have a bit different format in the calling part as I'm used to as there doesn't seems to be a filename just data - I have three Postman snapshots here how it looks when you call the original web service (it uploads a csv file):

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I try to use a handler like this it panics:

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("File")
defer file.Close()

// copy example
f, err := os.OpenFile("./downloaded", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
defer f.Close()
io.Copy(f, file)
```

It fails in the call to FormFile - I have an idea that its because of the File is in body. How can I make it work server side in Go with the client call from Postman?

### Edit

The panic it throws is:

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Comment: What does "It fails in the call to FormFile" mean, ie in which way it fails?

Comment: yes sorry, added it to the question - it throws : runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Comment: its like that the FormFile ("File") dont get the 'File' that is attached in the postman client

Comment: See does code example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39982229/723693 help you to figure out...